# Datatable issue with SearchPane column display

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, datatables

I have been playing around with the SearchPanes and managed to get it working quite nicely. If I do not use the Button, then the column layout value of "columns-4" works as intended.

The issue I am having is that once I add the button and the SearchPane opens in a "popup window" - it ignores the "columns-4" value altogether.

I have pasted my very rough code below. Perhaps it is just something that I am missing.

Any/all help would be greatly appreciated.

What I am trying to achieve is 4 columns across, currently it is just displaying 3 columns in the "popup".

```
$('#style-2').DataTable({
         "dom":  "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-6'l><'col-sm-12 col-md-6'Bf>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>" +                    
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
                "<'row'<'col-sm-12 col-md-5'i><'col-sm-12 col-md-7'p>>",
        "oLanguage": {
            "oPaginate": { "sPrevious": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-left"><line x1="19" y1="12" x2="5" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 19 5 12 12 5"></polyline></svg>', "sNext": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-arrow-right"><line x1="5" y1="12" x2="19" y2="12"></line><polyline points="12 5 19 12 12 19"></polyline></svg>' },
            "sInfo": "Showing page _PAGE_ of _PAGES_",
            "sSearch": '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-search"><circle cx="11" cy="11" r="8"></circle><line x1="21" y1="21" x2="16.65" y2="16.65"></line></svg>',
            "sSearchPlaceholder": "Search...",
           "sLengthMenu": "Results :  _MENU_",
        },
        "stripeClasses": [],
        "lengthMenu": [10, 20, 30],
        "pageLength": 10,
        stateSave: false,
        //stateSaveCallback: function(settings,data) {
        //    localStorage.setItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname, JSON.stringify(data) )
        //},
        //stateLoadCallback: function(settings) {
        //return JSON.parse( localStorage.getItem('DataTables_' + window.location.pathname ) )
        //},
        //stateDuration: 60 * 60 * 168,
        searchPanes: {
            layout: 'columns-4'//,
            //columns: [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ]
        },
        columnDefs: [
        {
            searchPanes: { show: true, },
            targets: [ 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ],
        },
        {
            searchPanes: { show: false, },
            targets: [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 21 ],
        },
            { visible: false, targets: [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20] },
            { orderable: true, targets: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4] },
            { type: 'alt-string', targets: [2] },
            { orderable: false, targets: '_all' }
        ],
        buttons: ['searchPanes']           
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems I was missing some elements (Config/Layout) when building the BUTTONS portion.

The following example gave me the answer to my question.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
      {
        extend: 'searchPanes',
        config: {
          layout:'columns-4'
        }
      }
    ]
  });
} );
```